# How does Iron Man's Galactus-Buster Armor work?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

Well, Galactus isn't Hulk. Galactus wields Power Cosmic which makes him god-class being.

How did Tony Stark overcome the power and invincibility of Power Cosmic? How does his Galactus-Buster Armor work?

[image: Tony stands topless in front of a control panel in front of his Galactus-Buster Armor: a beefy looking armour with the shoulders and up being purple and mimicking the look of Galactus with the large rectangular head and two "side prongs"]

Comment: What is that image from?

Comment: And why does it need to look like Galactus with the... antlers?

Comment: @J Doe looks very cool, nonetheless

Comment: “Galactus isn't Hulk” — there must have been a Galactus-Hulk mashup at some point.

Comment: A bunch of people you wouldn’t expect are able to hurt this Galactus. Like Ryu, for example. Now, we can keep going down that rabbit hole — is Ryu more powerful or Galactus less powerful. But the short answer is it’s just a video game and they don’t explain why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn’t currently an answer.
Since it only appears at the end of a video game (*Marvel vs. Capcom 3: Fate of Two Worlds*), all we know about the suit is that, after the defeat of Galactus, Tony Stark used the data from the battle to make the Galactus-Buster Armor.